# C#: Microsoft.Interop.Excel Refresh all not working

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have a really frustrating issue where whenever I call 
`RefreshAll()` from `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` it does not refresh the data when I open the workbook in excel and I have to manually click the refresh all button within excel... I have even tried calling refresh all via vba and it still does not refresh the data... I am always prompted with:

> "The PivotTable report was saved without underlying data. Use the
>   Refresh Data command to update the report."

Despite the fact that I already called the "Refresh all command."

```
public void applyMacro(string excelFile)
{
    var excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { Visible = false };
    var targetExcelFile = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
    try
    {
        string[] macros = addMacros(ref targetExcelFile);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            excelApplication.Run(macros[i]);
        targetExcelFile.RefreshAll();
        targetExcelFile.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    finally
    {
        excelApplication.Quit();
    }
}
```

and in vba have tried adding the following before calling the refresh:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
  For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
     qt.Refresh  BackGroundQuery:=False
  next qt
Next ws
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on your pivot table :

```
YourPivotTable.PivotCache().RefreshOnFileOpen = true;
YourPivotTable.SaveData = true;
```